# Is there a way to thank/upvote someones edits on your Question/Answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, voting

Just a quick bit of backstory. When I'm posting on Stack sites, I'm typically at work, so unable to devote my entire attention to the post.   Quite often, small typos/errors in maths/etc will slip through my fingers.

Often this is picked up by another member of the community, who'll go through and edit my post to fix up the errors, which brings me to my question.

Is there any way to specifically call out an edit that's been completed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A better knowledge base and a cleaner stack is its own reward. Editors aren't expecting any thanks, and there's no need to thank them.

But it is nice to be appreciated, and you'll think of leaving a @mention -ed comment on your post thanking them for the edit. We are more lenient with "thanks" comments, as @SevenSidedDie explains that "thanks" comments are valid as good feedback for the edit. However, they still do tend to get cleaned up, especially when the post is attracting more comments, so don't expect them to last long.

I have also experienced getting an inbox ping on a deleted comment, as @thedarkwanderer suggests, you can @mention the editor in the comments (even if their name won't show up in the autocomplete, thanks @doppelgreener). However, the text the pinged user can see is limited to a few characters, and I cannot totally vouch that a user gets the ping 100% of the time, and how long it will last in their inbox.

Alternatively, you can drop by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), @mention the editor and say thanks there. This will only work for users who have been in chat for at least a week (most editors check in sometimes, anyway), you'll know that the ping will work if it auto-completes.

Comment: If you do use comments, editors are `@pingable` in a comment reply, even if their name won't show up in the autocomplete.

Comment: We tend to go easy on comments that give thanks for edits, since discussing edits is usually within the purpose of comments. At the very least, it's useful feedback that the edits are good!

Comment: You can @mention people who are not currently in chat, as long as they have been in chat "recently". I wasn't able to find a clear timeframe for "recently" but I think it's a couple days.

Comment: You can @mention a thanks, and then delete it safely soon thereafter; Even when a comment has been deleted the person at-mentioned will see the comment blurb in their inbox temporarily.  Or at least, I get deleted comments in my inbox sometimes, so I figure this is how it happens.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Chat pings on a user are available for about a week since their most recent visit into chat.

Comment: @doppelgreener So the user needs to be less than a week inactive in chat for them to receive a chat ping?

Comment: @daze413 Yes. It's a pretty narrow window.